# DNA cryptography mutation process: finding substrings

Tags: c#, regex

I have this sequence of amino acid: `PhePheLeoArgStopValGlyArgTyrStopPheArgGleHis`

I want to apply a point of mutation on this sequence so that the result will be a number of keys generated from the above sequence like such as the following:

```
key1:PhePheLeoArgStopValGlyArgTyrStopPheArgGleHis
key2:ValGlyArgTyrStopPheArgGleHis
key3:PheArgGleHis
```

So when ever it reaches `Stop`, it creates a key consisting of the rest of the string.

I tried the following code but does not work as I expected:

```
string mRNA = textBox3.Text;
string Rna = mRNA.Replace("Stop", "*");
string[] keys = Rna.Split('*');
foreach (string key in keys)
{
    listBox1.Items.Add( key);
}
```

Can any one assist me in fixing the code?

Comment: Is there any requirement to use regex? You could easily accomplish this LastIndexOf or other ways.

Comment: how? can you help me .

Comment: added an examply of how to do with IndexOf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a function like this:

```
static IEnumerable<string> Mutate(string input)
{
  if (input == null || input.Length == 0) { yield break; }
  yield return input;
  int pos = 0;
  while (pos < input.Length)
  {
    int index = input.IndexOf("Stop", pos);
    if (index == -1 || index == input.Length - 4) { yield break; }
    index += 4;
    yield return input.Substring(index);
    pos = index;
  }
}
```

Then do

```
string mRNA = textBox3.Text;
foreach (string key in Mutate(mRNA))
{
  listBox1.Items.Add(key);
}
```

I've tested this solution with inputs that:

- are null,
- are empty,
- begin with "Stop",
- end with "Stop",
- have multiple "Stop"s in a row and
- have no "Stop"s.

Comment: Very robust solution!

Comment: thank you all my friend you really helped me to solve my solution

Comment: thank you i used your code and it solve my problem @CallumWatkins

Answer (score 3):

I would use an indexOf solution to solve this. See below:

```
 var rna = "PhePheLeoArgStopValGlyArgTyrStopPheArgGleHis";
 var keys = new List<string>();
 var pos = -1;

 //prime the loop by adding the first item           
 keys.Add(rna);
 listBox1.Items.Add(keys.Last());

 //loop through all the occurrecnces of "Stop" and add they key
 while ((pos = rna.IndexOf("Stop", pos + 1)) >= 0)
 {
     keys.Add(rna.Substring(pos+4));
     listBox1.Items.Add(keys.Last());
 }
```

Comment: Pointed to your answer from mine. It's probably more efficient, but I think the `NextMatch` solution is more readable (no magic integer values) and flexible (regex). Upvoted...

Comment: If the input begins with "Stop" this does not work. The while loop needs `>= 0` instead of `> 0` I believe.

Comment: @CallumWatkins - thanks updated answer to reflect your suggestion.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes - to each his own, I find this more readable. With a string this short I don't think efficiency is all that important.

Comment: Well, this is a test string. I presume RNA strings may in reality be just a *tiny* bit larger. And yes, to each his own. I'd certainly use `var pattern = "Stop"` and then `pattern.Length` instead of the literal `4` though.

Comment: will work, but explaining why or some comments may be helpful, as well as descriptive variable names.

Answer (score 1):

`Split` is probably one of the most overused constructs. It's easy to see why because it literally splits the problem into sections, and that's what programming is all about when you take a birds eye view.

However, in this case you are better off searching in the string using [`Match` and `NextMatch`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.match(v=vs.110).aspx):

> This method returns the first substring in input that matches the regular expression pattern. You can retrieve subsequent matches by repeatedly calling the returned Match object's `Match.NextMatch` method.

Then you can use [`Match#Index + Match#Length`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.match(v=vs.110).aspx) to find the index of the "key" (at least if this is everything after the match, as you've indicated). The key itself then can simply be retrieved by using [`String#Substring`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hxthx5h6(v=vs.110).aspx).

So here is the example code (as you've tried hard enough, it seems):

```
var rna = "PhePheLeoArgStopValGlyArgTyrStopPheArgGleHis";
var pattern = "Stop";

var keys = new List<string>();

// the entire rna string is apparently also a key
keys.Add(rna);

Match match = Regex.Match(rna, pattern);

// loop while the pattern is found
while (match.Success)
{
    // we want everything after the match
    var from = match.Index + match.Length;
    keys.Add(rna.Substring(from));

    // and then retrieve the next match (if any)
    match = match.NextMatch();
}
```

You'll need:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
```

at the start of your file for this to work.

---

If you just search for a static string you can also use [`IndexOf`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7cct0x33(v=vs.110).aspx). In that case you can find the start of the next string by adding `"Stop".Length` to the found index (after checking if it actually found the `Stop` string, of course).

For an example of this have a look [at this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50605048/589259).